# Skype for Business APP SDK general availability

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I already know this is not the ideal place to ask this, but it's all I have.

Any idea when will the final version be available? 
Also, can you share any licensing details for the public release?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/feedback) for other ways to communicate with the Microsoft team.  The email or 'uservoice' routes might be better for this type of question.]

There is no current date for the final version: this will depend on feedback received on the preview version.

As per the license.pdf in the [SDK download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/download), the App SDK can be used (without additional cost) to join any Skype for Business meeting that is also attended by a licensed Skype for Business user (via another client).

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I checked that page beforehand but didn't see an email option. I also read the license.pdf in the SDK release but I assumed that are the terms for the preview version of the SDK which does not allow you to deploy the solution in production or to more than 100 external users.

Comment: Hi Alex - there's a link on that page to send email about bugs/issues to the 'Skype developer insiders email box'.  You can also use that to send non-technical enquiries like this one.  I'll update the page to say so.  Yes, you're right that the license terms are for the preview, but most terms should stay the same for the public release (other than lifting the 100 user limit of course).  Again, please send email if you have questions/concerns about this.  Thanks.